# How to call another function in the function and loop the results by storing in the variable?

Tags: php, function, for-loop, return

I would like to ask an question about the usage of function in PHP. How can I call another function in PHP?

```
 ......
 $Table = "<table border=1>";
 $Table .= "<tr>"; 
 function bookingHour($Table){
    for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){ //loop the hour 1-6 and display the content by function booking()
    echo $i;
        $Table .= "<td align=center>" . booking($array, $rmNum, $dateTime) . "</td>";
    }
    return $Table;
 }
 $Table .= "</tr>";
 $Table .= "</table><br>";
 echo $Table;
 ......
```

It showed the error messages:Undefined variable: array, rmNum, dateTime are not defined.
Does the function implemented wrongly so I cannot see the table shows?

Comment: You need to call the function `bookingHour`.Now you have defined it.

Comment: Sorry I explain it badly, I would like to ask how can I calling another function in the function. It said that $array, $rmNum, $dateTime are undefined.

Comment: its outside the scope by they way, and the way you're thinking, it wont append it inside the `<tr>`, but it will append on the end string  (after `</table><br>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this:

```
      $Table = "<table border=1>";
         $Table .= "<tr>"; 
$Tab="";
         function bookingHour($Tab){
            for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){ //loop the hour 1-6 and display the content by function booking()
            echo $i;
                $Tab .= "<td align=center>" . booking($array, $rmNum, $dateTime) . "</td>";// otherwise table tag will repeate multiple time and won't display correctly.
            }
            return $Tab;
         }
        $Table.=$Tab;
         $Table .= "</tr>";
         $Table .= "</table><br>";
         echo $Table;
```

in you other function `booking($array, $rmNum, $dateTime)` you are using `$array, $rmNum, $dateTime` so they should have some values assigned to them.

Comment: Is $Table.=$tab instead of $Table=.$tab;??

Comment: The system also said $Tab is undefined.

Comment: it is because in bookingHour i was passing $Table not $Tab now try and tell if still getting problem.

Comment: calling by "bookingHour($Table);"?

Comment: just replace new code to old one or pass $Tab to bookingHour($Tab).

Comment: I have solved this part and thanks a lot of your help:)